# Restore kernel version

Tags: raspbian, kernel

I have Raspbian 3.12.X, and I want to compile modules, so I installed a distribution with kernel headers:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-rpi-rpfv linux-headers-rpi-rpfv
```

Then, I tell Raspbian to boot the newly installed kernel by appending this at end of `/boot/config.txt` and reboot the Raspberry Pi:

```
kernel=vmlinuz-3.10-3-rpi
initramfs initrd.img-3.10-3-rpi followkernel
```

Now I want to restore version `3.12.X`. When I launch `rpi-update` I get
`Your firmware is already up to date`,  but `uname -a` shows:

```
Debian 3.10.11-1+rpi6 (2014-04-27) armv6l GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to revert to a particular kernel/firmware version.

Go to https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-firmware/commits/master and find the commit key for the version you want.  Then use the following command substituting the commit key for the one you want.

sudo rpi-update 5ea0f44b673eaa52c578fcd6480495f19cd53d97 (example)